# Yii FrameWork Controller name is added int he url

Tags: yii

I am working on a web application that is using Yii framework. the website default URL and the page which is pre-defined having the following URL

> http://example.com (base url)
>
> http://example.com/contact (page url)

However, I have a problem with the custom page they are shown with the following URL

> http://example.com/yes-page-name

I checked the file that is calling the page and found the following

```
<div class="nek" align="center">
   <a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("/yes-". trim($val['pagname_slug']))?>">
        <img class="mylogo"src="<?php echo FunctionsV3::getmyCompanyLogo($company_id);?>">
   </a>
</div>
```

**`config.php`** setting is as followed

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'class' => 'UrlManager', 
        'urlFormat'=>'path',            
        'showScriptName'=>false,            
        'rules'=>array(     
            '' => 'web/index',
            '<action:('.$patern.')>' => 'web/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',                
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

I would like to remove **`yes-`** from the url as it is not user friendly. Any help on this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: what is in the `$patern` in config.php?

Comment: Omer here is the $patern in config.php

$patern="|cuisine|signup|signin|merchantsignup|contact|searcharea";
$patern.="|menu|checkout|paymentoption|receipt|logout|paypalinit|paypalverify";
$patern.="|OrderHistory|Profile|howItWork|forgotPassword|PageSetlanguage|stripeInit";
$patern.="|MercadoInit|RenewSuccesful|Browse|PaylineInit|Paylineverify|sisowinit";

Comment: so what does it do when you remove `yes-` from the line `<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("/yes-". trim($val['pagname_slug']))?>` i think it should work correctly , and is the listed `urlManager` above complete? and please add the information in your question by editing it not in the comments.

Comment: it does not work when i remove yes- url 404

Comment: ok can you share the controller and the action that is used to display the specified url in the link